# Fetch Id of a selected data from a array of data

Tags: react-native

I have a list of array id but when I select any data I want the id of the selected data, I tried using map but it gives me a list of id's in a array. Please let me know how to do this, thanks in advance

Comment: Please add code also

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example in order to understand your question better?

map() will always return an array, if you are getting an array with the desired value and a long list of undefined, then just add

```
.filter(e => e)
```

at the end.

If you want to iterate and obtain a single value, reduce() might be what you are looking for.